# uninitialized constant EventController::TempFile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a temp file in my rails application. Here is the controller code:

```
private
def tmp_example
 temp_file = TempFile.new('logo')
 # save uploaded file
 File.open(temp_file.path, "w") do |f|
   f.write session[:user_params]["logo"].delete(:file).read
   f.close
 end
end
```

I have required the tempfile in application.rb

```
require 'tempfile'
```

But still i am getting error:

> uninitialized constant UsersController::TempFile

Can anyone how to fix this issue thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html), you should use `Tempfile` instead of `TempFile`:

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new('logo')
```